# PHP something faster than explode to get filename from URL

Tags: php, url, explode

My URL's can be absolute or relative:

```
$rel = "date/album/001.jpg";
$abs = "http://www.site.com/date/album/image.jpg";

function getFilename($url) {
    $imgName = explode("/", $url);
    $imgName = $imgName[count($imgName) - 1];
    echo $imgName;
}
```

There must be a faster way to do this right?
Maybe a reg expression? But that's Chinese to me..

Comment: do you really need a "faster" way?

Comment: looping over lotsaaa images, yes please...

Comment: just as a tip you can use end() to get the last value of an array

Comment: so what? is your current function not fast enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`basename`](http://php.net/basename) returns the file name:

```
function getFilename($url) {
    return basename($url);
}
```

You can even strip the file name extension.

Answer (score 4):

```
substr( $url , strrpos( $url , "/" ) + 1 );
```

or

```
substr( strrchr( $url , "/" ) , 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe basename is the quickest one, but you can also use

```
$url = "http://www.mmrahman.co.uk/image/bg830293.jpg";
getFileName($url){
    $parts = pathinfo($url);
    return $parts['basename'];
}
```

pathinfo also allow you to get filename, extension, dirname etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `dirname` function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)